# How to simulate an Angular filter in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ember.js

What is logic behind angular filter? We use angular filter in below way

```
var users = [
  {
    name: "lokesh",
    age: 25
  },
 {
    name: "john",
    age: 20
  }
]

<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search">
   {{user.name}} {{user.age}}
</div>
```

Is there any such filter in Ember.js or how to a such filter in plain javascript. Filter should return objects which has that user typed word. Moreover that filter should be like a independent component. It should work with any number of properties in the object

```
var search = "lokesh";
users.filter(function (user) {
  return user.name == search || user.age == search;
});
```

The above filter works for 2 properties name and age. I want a filter that can work with any number of properties. More over Filter should match partial strings aswell unlike above example which checks for ==

Comment: I would recommend that you look at the source code for the angular js filter and adapt it for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let narrowedUserList = users.filter(function (user) {
for(var key in user){
    if(user[key].toString().indexOf(filterValue) >= 0)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically use `Object.keys`:

```
users.filter(d => Object.keys(d).some(key => d[key] == search))
```

Now its easy to create a `ember.js` helper, or just a utility function or a computed property template. To get the live update working is a bit a challenge, but nothing impossible.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) are a little different to ember, registering is simple, using the same logic you have above we can create the simple search functionality you're after.

Registering a custom filter is as simple as this:

```
app.filter('search', function() {
  return function(user, search) {
    return user.name == search || user.age == search;
  };
});
```

Working angular filter demo: https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/287/

Comment: I did not ask for custom filter. Logic behind the filter

Comment: Please do not mark my question down because your OP was not clear, your title was "How AngularJS filter work" I provided a working demo of an angularjs filter using your logic.

Comment: It wont allow to upvote, unless you edit. please edit and save again

Comment: The question is clear you seem to have stopped reading past `How Angular filter work?`